# Reading RTF Files line by line in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf, readlines

I am working on a C# WPF tool, which shall read different text file types and analyze the file line by line.

It works properly for example for a .asc text file:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(myFile.asc)) {
  AnalyzeCurrentLine(line);
}
```

Now it becomes difficult for me reading a RTF file. I still want to read it line by line. The format of the text is not relevant. Is a `RichTextBox` object the correct way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `RichTextBox` to load your RTF and then read its content line by line like this:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
string rtf = File.ReadAllText("file.rtf");
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rtf)))
    rtb.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);

string text = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Works as desired. Thanks a lot :-)